# Warnung: Error in terms.formula: Object 'risktable' not found

Tags: r, shiny

When I execute this code I get the error:

> Warnung: Error in terms.formula: Object 'risktable' not found
>    [No stack trace available]

but I don't know where it came from. I've tried to put risktable in a different position in the argument, but the fault lies with him.

```
for (n in names(rv$prog_validationstudylist)) {
      fit <- rv$prognostic_classifier[[n]]$kaplan_estimator$fit
      risktable <- rv$prognostic_classifier[[n]]$risktable

      filename <- paste0(rv$plotdir,
                         n,
                         "_Prognostic_Kaplan-Meier_Plot.png")
      sigident::plot_survplot(
        fit = fit,
        risktable = risktable,
        filename = filename
      )
    }
```

Comment: Does the error appear on the first iteration or a later one? What's the output of 'names(rv$prognostic_classifier[[n]])` ? does the object 'rv$prognostic_classifier[[n]]' have a field named 'risktable' at each iteartion of the loop?

Comment: The error appears in the first iteration
rv$prognostic_classifier[[n]]$risktable gives me a object risktable in each iteration.